# child rows in a row for anychart.ganttResource();

Tags: anychart, anychart-8.2

i am trying to look for example of showing child rows in a row for anychart.ganttResource();
which should be a like the below url example

https://playground.anychart.com/docs/v8/samples/GANTT_Elements_Labels_03

i tried putting children[] and post elements in it but not able to see down array of child rows

so if you know any way we can add child rows to anycharts.ganttResource() please help me

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely the same approach will work for Gantt Resource chart. For details, check [the sample](https://playground.anychart.com/docs/v8/samples/GANTT_Resource_Chart_02). You can learn more about Gantt Resource data hierarchy in [the article](https://docs.anychart.com/Gantt_Chart/Resource_Chart#hierarchy).